# What is the correct way to dispose of a producer thread after the consumer thread gets notified of a synchronized change and falls out?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

My understanding is that after a consumer is notified of the synchronized variable change, if the consumer `Thread` falls out and exits there's nothing stopping the producer from cranking along.  What is the correct way to dispose of the producer thread?  Is there anything preventing `Thread.interrupt()` from being called from the conumser's `run()` method?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
//in consumer
public void run() {
    synchronized( checkSolution) {
        while (!checkSolution.getIsSolutionValid) {
            try{
                checkSolution.wait()
            } catch( InterruptedException ignore) {}
        } 
        //valid soln received
        System.out.println("reference");
        checkSolution.interrupt();
        doAmazingWorkWithSolution();
    }
    //MARK
}
//in producer (checkSolution)
public synchronized boolean getIsSolutionValid() { return isSolutionValid; }
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        try{
            synchronized( this) {
                if( fSolution.size() != correctSize) {
                    isSolutionValid = false;
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                 } else {
                     System.out.println(" Solution is correct size.");
                     isSolutionValid = true;
                     notifyAll();
                 }  
             }
         } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
             //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
             return;
    }
    }
}
```

Now, here's what I've noticed and I really don't understand:

1. Under any successful interrupt, the producer's interrupt flag is set but it executes the code in the `else` block many many many times before finally shutting down.  How can I avoid spamming the if/else statement during the `notify`?
2. if I move the checkSolution.interrupt() and "amazing work" method call to the line marked `//MARK` it interrupts significantly slower, executes the amazing work call but oddly never prints the `println("reference");
3. If I remove the return statement form the `InterruptedException` it receives the interrupt and ends up in the `Exception` block for one step but spams the else statement a bajillion times, and then starts plugging away again back on the `Thread.sleep` block as if the interrupted flag had been reset.
4. the `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in the producer's `InterruptException` is something that I've seen in other people's code but it doesn't seem to do anything here if I include it or not.

These are minor things I'm confused about.  The major question is how to shut the producer down, as efficiently as possible, as close as possible to the consumer thread after the consumer gotten what it needs.

Comment: How is `isValidSolution` declared? Volatile?

Comment: @assylias, isSolutionValid is a private boolean instance variable of the producer class, and...I entered in `!isSolutionValid` for the consumer's `while` condition instead of `!checkSolution.getIsSolutionValid` . changing now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working at too low a level. If there is only one producer and consumer, you can use a `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue` to block the consumer until the producer has done its work.

For the purpose of `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html. It's a bad idea to do this

```
catch( InterruptedException ignore) {}
```

in a `while` loop. More details in the linked article.

Comment: thanks for the article pointer. Oddly, just came across that today myself!  Just throttled the exception to simplify the code posted in forum.